# Working with files in C - gives incompatible integer to pointer conversion (code is taken from The C book)

Tags: c

I got very stupid error and I have no idea why it is occurring in my code. I simply use code from The C book and it seems that nothing special is going on here..
Thanks for any help.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;    // Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *'
    fp = fopen(argv[1], 'r');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");` (the second argument is a string, not an int)

Comment: Nice nick! La-la-la-la-la-la-la-la ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ;)))

Comment: Who, me? LaLaLaLa!!!!

Comment: Also needed is `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: True, but it must have been included to get the prototype for `fopen()` so that the compiler can generate the error that's shown.

Comment: Can you quote a chapter/page number in 'The C book'?  What is the exact title and who wrote it — is there a URL you can give?  Is this a typo in your copying from the book or a typo in the book?

Answer (score 7):

You should be using `fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")`.  The error is because you're passing a character (EDIT: aka an integer type) (single quotes) where it expects a string (double quotes).